# orientationEvent.gamma is taking +180 to -180 degrees

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, mobile-safari

After long sleepless nights, I have finally managed to integrate a decent tilt handler into a plugin that I am working on, that can detect if a browser can handle tilt, then if the device running that browser can handle tilt, the device's potrait or landscape orientation.... blah blah.

After everything was complete, I began testing it on difference devices. However, an interesting nuisance showed up when I tried it on my ipad air running ios 9.3.2. Here is the part of the code that I use to test the orientation:

```
function handleOrientation(event)
{
    var alphaQ = event.alpha;
    var betaQ = event.beta;
    var gammaQ = event.gamma;
    var divnamehere = document.getElementById("somediv");
    divnamehere.innerHTML = "Alpha:" + alphaQ + "<br>Beta: " +
                            betaQ + "<br>Gamma: " + gammaQ;
}
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, false);
```

Now this shows a Gamma value that exceeds +-90 degrees and can give up to +-180 degrees. But the Alpha's limit is from 0 to 360 degrees, for beta it's -180 to 180 degrees and for Gamma it would be -90 to +90 (not 180).

Only reason I can think of would be that ipad gyroscope works differently. Can someone please confirm? Uncle google is failing me.

Comment: I did use a check to limit it to 90 degrees, which is easy, but please, can someone confirm if it's the difference in gyroscope in different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confirmed. In iPad Air, Gamma rotation is +180 to -180 instead of +90 to -90.